B. Alan Wallace’s students
Is it possible to connect with students of B. Alan Wallace through this forum?
I have been desperate to get blessings/ initiation in his lineage.
Thank you!

I presume you know there are various web sites, with a Contact page etc.? And several physical places in a few different countries, also with their own web sites.

Thank you. Yes, I've used the Contact page. I'll keep trying all available avenues.
